# What's the name of this class of transcendental numbers?

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

I'm considering the set $$\left\{\sin(k)\mid k\in\Bbb Z\backslash \left\{0\right\}\right\}.$$ All of its members are transcendental numbers, but together they don't form the complete set of all transcendental numbers between $-1$ and $1$.

Does this set of numbers belong to, and form on $\left[-1,1\right]$ completely, a differently named class of numbers? What would that name be?

**Edit due to comment.** Or, if not, would these numbers belong to (but not completely form between $-1$ and $1$) a differently named subclass of transcendental numbers?

Comment: It seems unlikely that something so specific would have its own name. If you want shorter notation you could just call it $\sin(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})$.

Comment: All of these numbers are [elementary numbers](http://math.mit.edu/~tchow/closedform.pdf) in the sense of Timothy Y. Chow. Also, it's probably known within fairly narrow bounds what their transcendence measures are (probably all their transcendence measures are the same), but I don't know much about this. However, none of these properties will characterize the set of numbers you're interested in, and I doubt there is any interest in such a characterization. Perhaps more interesting would be to obtain such a characterization for the values of $e^z$ when $z=x+iy$ with $x,y \in {\mathbb Q}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no name for this class.
You will end up with $\aleph_0$ items in the set which is dense in $(-1,1)\cap\mathbb{R}$.
In fact, proving that this is dense is going to be hard.

Comment: Actually the fact that they are dense in this interval follows pretty much immediately from the Weyl equidistribution theorem.